# Pythonic way to apply a list of functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still new to python and I was wondering if there was a way to simplify this function into something close to a one-liner:

```
filters = [lambda x: is_big(x), lambda x: is_wide(x), lambda x: is_gray(x)]
def filter(input):
    for func in filters:
        if(not func(input)):
            return False
        else:
            continue
    return True
```

Assume the functions in the filters list return booleans. Basically is there any way I can do something like `all(apply input to each filter)`?

Comment: FYI, `[lambda x: is_big(x), lambda x: is_wide(x), lambda x: is_gray(x)]` is equivalent to `[is_big, is_wide, is_gray]`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Right! Yeah I knew that but let's be honest, I didn't actually know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
all(func(input) for func in filters)
```

Comment: Oh interesting. Is there any documentation I can read up on this short hand notation of `func(input) for func in filters`?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on short circuit? Doesn't `all` return False after the first False?

Comment: @Dzhao: it's a generator expression. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
result = all(f(input) for f in filters)
```

Comment: But doesn't `all` already stop executing after a first fail? See my edited answer for what I mean.

Comment: @BAH is right, so you should use a list comprehension instead of a generator expression.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list comprehension to get filtered output from your input:

```
filtered = [x for x in input if all(f(x) for f in filters)]
```

You could also use the built in filter:

```
complete_filter = lambda x: all(f(x) for f in filters)
filtered = filter(complete_filter, input)
```

On a side note (not sure what others mean by the fact that `all` doesn't short circuit). See below:

```
def f():
    print "in f"
    return True

def g():
    print "in g"
    return False

def h():
    print "in h"
    return True

filters = [f, g, h]
print all(fn() for fn in filters)
```

This prints

```
in f
in g
False
>>>
```

Comment: It ***did not*** execute function `h`. Otherwise you would have seen `"in h"` in the output. Am I missing something here? Unless I'm not seeing something really obvious here, it short circuited on `g` returning `False`.